# Acumatica Report Designer - Sort Groups by Sum

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a report in Report Designer. I have a bunch of SOShipLines that I'm trying to group by item number, sort in descending order by the sum of their shipped quantities, and only show the top 5 items. But no matter what I try, I can't get this sorting to work, nor can I find an option to limit to only 5 entries.

The reason I'm doing this in Report Designer is that I also need to be able to show the grand total at the bottom of the report. I already have a generic inquiry that does everything I need to do except show this bottom line total. Is there a way to show such a total in a generic inquiry, or is this something that has to be done in a report? If it has to be done in a report, how can I get the sorting and limiting to work?

Comment: For GIs you can't show a row just for Totals. In the Report Designer, try creating a formula something like (sum(shipped.qty)) for the Sort tab in the schema.

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried. The Sorting tab in the "Build Schema" window doesn't even let me enter formulas. I tried entering `=Sum([SOShipLine.ShippedQty])` in the "Sorting" window from the Properties tab, but this didn't help. I also tried just using ShippedQty without the Sum().

Comment: Hmm, Id make a support case.